# React native monorepo with PNPM

Tags: react-native, monorepo, pnpm

### My goal

I am trying to use React native monorepo with PNPM, because I need performance of pnpm.

### Expected

I should be able to bundle React native app with `pnpm android` and start development server with `pnpm start`.

#### Actual results

I can bundle app, but ***I cant start metro server***. I always get this error: [image]

## More info

I have node v16.14.2, react native v0.69.

I know default metro bundler doesn't support symlinks (https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/1252#issuecomment-667600769), which pnpm use, so I tried to patch metro in `metro.config.js`:
[image: metro.config.js]

**This works perfectly fine with pure React native repo like here** e.g: https://github.com/gjhughes/react-native-pnpm-example

My project structure looks like this:

```
project
└───shared
└───backend
│   │   package.json
│   
└───frontend
│   │   package.json
│   
└───mobile-app
│   │   package.json
```

Here is my `pnpm-workspace.yaml`:

[image: pnpm-workspace.yaml]

I am desperate. Is it even possible?

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use pnpm without symlinks. Create a `.npmrc` in the root of your monorepo with the following setting:

```
node-linker=hoisted
```

Remove node_modules and run `pnpm install`. Related docs: https://pnpm.io/npmrc#node-linker

Comment: This breaks everything, I have to then change all paths in `settings.gradle` and even then I can't bundle the app. The symlink problem should be resolved by `@rnx-kit`, which has probably problem with the pnpm workspace.

Comment: React 0.72 has support for symlinks, although you have to enable it in a config file.  It will be the default in 0.73.   https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/06/21/0.72-metro-package-exports-symlinks.  I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i made a boilerplate working with monorepos in case you need it

Using react-native 0.72.1 on a monorepo like turbo that enjoy it ;)

https://github.com/Morraycage/turbo-react-native-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

In your `.npmrc` you can do next:

To see if there are any problems with symlinks and make anything work you can start with

```
node-linker=hoisted
```

But this will break the point of having `pnpm` at all

For my case these lines did the job, and ready to be extended if necessary

```
public-hoist-pattern[]=*eslint*
public-hoist-pattern[]=*prettier*
public-hoist-pattern[]=*react-native*
public-hoist-pattern[]=*metro*
```

(note that `eslint` and `prettier` reused from defaults)

Reference further details here https://pnpm.io/npmrc#hoist-pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to take advantage of pnpm and avoid the node-linker=hoisted
option, you can take a look at this [great article](https://runreactnative.dev/posts/pnpm-react-native) that explains how to make it works.

To summarize it, you need to

1- add a bunch of packages to make the react-native cli works with pnpm:

```
pnpm install @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
```

2- re-install your pods

```
# in ios folder
bundle exec pod install
```

3- allow metro to understand symlink (prior to RN72, it natively can't) with @rnx-kit

```
pnpm install @rnx-kit/metro-config @rnx-kit/metro-resolver-symlinks
```

change your metro.config.js file to this:

```
const { makeMetroConfig } = require('@rnx-kit/metro-config')
const MetroSymlinksResolver = require('@rnx-kit/metro-resolver-symlinks')

module.exports = makeMetroConfig({
  projectRoot: __dirname,
  resolver: {
     resolveRequest: MetroSymlinksResolver(),
  },
})
```

4 - extra step to build on android

```
pnpm install react-native-gradle-plugin jsc-android
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation is similar to yours, I solved this problem through the expo official documentation。

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/monorepos/

to create and set the metro.config.js in mobile folder

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const path = require('path');

// Find the project and workspace directories
const projectRoot = __dirname;
// This can be replaced with `find-yarn-workspace-root`
const monorepoRoot = path.resolve(projectRoot, '../..');

const config = getDefaultConfig(projectRoot);

// 1. Watch all files within the monorepo
config.watchFolders = [monorepoRoot];
// 2. Let Metro know where to resolve packages and in what order
config.resolver.nodeModulesPaths = [
  path.resolve(projectRoot, 'node_modules'),
  path.resolve(monorepoRoot, 'node_modules'),
];

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: and you can watch my github project to fork a full stack monorepo project